# How does control flows in html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I am new to web programming. I have to design a web application. I want to use Ajax in my html pages. I have studied about how to use ajax,but I am unable to understand the flow of control in the html doc given below:

I usually program in C language. There I can figure out the flow of program, but not in this html doc. Plz help me.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function loadXMLDoc()
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
        <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: the `<script>` part defines the function `loadXMLDoc` and the `html` part assigns it to the `onclick` event of the button. The function should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=...` part assigns a function to the `onreadystatechange` event of the `xmlhttp` object

Comment: I want to ask that does it follow top down approach within a function? If yes , then how come open() and send() method is written after the code that modifies innerhtml of the division"myDiv"? I think open(),send() method should be written before onreadystatechange. Plz comment.

Comment: The function goes like this: declare xmlhttp; initialize it with the correct type based on the browser; assign a function to the readystatechange event (the function doesn't get executed, just assigned: when onreadystatechange happens, do this); specify the type of the request (open); send the request;

Comment: when the request gets a response  the code inside the function assigned to the event onreadystatechange gets executed and modifies the div